# Terraform cloud issue fetching google artifact registry versions

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I wrote a script to pull the latest image version from google artifact registry so that my terraform cloud deployments will always deploy the latest version of my GCP image.

```
exec 2>/dev/null 

curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com > install.sh
bash install.sh --disable-prompts --install-dir=./ >/dev/null 
PATH=$PATH:./google-cloud-sdk/bin
printf '%s' "$GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS" > key.json
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=key.json

SHA=$(gcloud artifacts docker images list us-docker.pkg.dev/$2/gcr.io/$1 --sort-by="~UPDATE_TIME" --limit=1 --format="value(format('{0}',version))")

while [[ ! "$SHA" =~ ^sha256\:[0-9a-f]{64}$ ]]; do
    // do some processing here
    SHA=$(gcloud artifacts docker images list us-docker.pkg.dev/$2/gcr.io/$1 --sort-by="~UPDATE_TIME" --limit=1 --format="value(format('{0}',version))")
    sleep 5
done

cat <<EOF
{
  "sha": "$SHA"
}
EOF
```

It is used like so in a terraform configuration.

```
data "external" "lookup-codes-ol-svc-image-sha" {
  program = ["${path.module}/scripts/get-image-sha.sh","${local.lookup_codes_ol_svc_name}","${var.common_project_id}"]
}
```

with cloud run container defined like so

```
containers {
      image = "gcr.io/${var.common_project_id}/${local.lookup_codes_ol_svc_name}@${data.external.lookup-codes-ol-svc-image-sha.result["sha"]}"
```

The script works perfectly but often on terraform cloud runs the sha is blank.  There appears to be no rhyme or reason to it....it works sometimes, dosent work sometimes.  I REALLY need to figure out why this is and if there is something I need to do to improve the chance that it runs right.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Since this is a cloud setup, there arent a whole lot of switches or changes I can make.

Edit:  Does anyone know how to get detailed logs out of terraform cloud?  I dont see any errors on the api console on the google side but I dont thin I believe that either.  The script works every time locally and about half of the time in terraform cloud.  I just need to find out why so i can fix it.

Another update:  I found out that in terraform cloud it seems like sometimes containers are reused which caused a directory not empty error in the google cloud sdk install.  I added some checks and retries around that bit of the script which improved the success rate but still see occasional errors...

Latest Update:  I "may" have solved it..  After a lot of careful digging into what is going on on theterraform cloud side the following code has shown to work so far.  Ill keep testing and after a week with no failures, Id sya its good for anyone elses interested in doing something like this.

Here is the final script.  This has held up for a week so far so Im thinking this solves it.

```
datenum=$(expr $(date +%s) + 0)
dirstring="$((datenum % 10000))dir"
retries=5
while true; do
  res=$(mkdir $dirstring 2>&1)
  if echo "$res" | grep -Eq '^.{0}$'; then
    break
  fi
  sleep 5
  datenum=$(expr $(date +%s) + 0)
  dirstring="$((datenum % 10000))dir"
  retries=$((retries - 1))
  if [ $retries -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Failed to create directory"
    exit 1
  fi
done

curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com > install.sh
bash install.sh --disable-prompts --install-dir=./$dirstring >/dev/null 
PATH=$PATH:./$dirstring/google-cloud-sdk/bin
printf '%s' "$GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS" > key.json
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=key.json

SHA=$(gcloud artifacts docker images list us-docker.pkg.dev/$2/gcr.io/$1 --sort-by="~UPDATE_TIME" --limit=1 --format="value(format('{0}',version))")
retries=5
while true; do
  if echo "$SHA" | grep -Eq '^sha256\:[0-9a-f]{64}$'; then
    break
  fi
  sleep 5
  SHA=$(gcloud artifacts docker images list us-docker.pkg.dev/$2/gcr.io/$1 --sort-by="~UPDATE_TIME" --limit=1 --format="value(format('{0}',version))")
  retries=$((retries - 1))
  if [ $retries -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Failed to get SHA for image us-docker.pkg.dev/$2/gcr.io/$1"
    exit 1
  fi
done

cat <<EOF
{
  "sha": "$SHA"
}
EOF
```

Comment: Why not simply use the `latest` tag?

Comment: latest had a similar problem..  My terraform deploy deploys entire app so it needs to check the version of all containers and update to latest.  This was written to get latest sha and update container if it was old.

Comment: I see you're suppressing all messages that are written to stderr, perhaps you could remove that first line in the script and see any errors that are emitted